# Where do I get all the phonemes of RP English in audio?

Tags: english, phonology, pronunciation, phonemes, resource-request

I need an authoritative link or a standard which linguists use as a reference point (to compare). It would be not bad if someone knows more or less right phonemes (wav) links (with correct formants ..etc). Only direct links to wav-files. (If it's free and isn't proprietary of course).

All 44 of them. For example: ash, epsilon, schwa, theta, wedge...

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/multimedia/pron/chart/chart.shtml - a chart but I can't extract audio (1 file = 1 phoneme)

Comment: http://lingvoforum.net/index.php?action=notify;topic=66333.0 - best possible answer

Comment: What do you mean by "RP English"? Some people use this to refer to a modern variety of English, while others use it to refer to a historical variety that isn't actually spoken by anyone anymore due to phonetic changes that have affected British English speakers' pronunciation.